# html table in email template wont have a max-width of 600px and be centred on page in outlook desktop or outlook.com

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, email-templates

Ive coded an html email template with a tabled markup (so that it can run cross email client). Ive run into one issue with centring one of the table blocks, whilst at the same time keeping it at a max width of 600px that scales down for smaller devices.

The issue is in in both Outlook's desktop client and outlook.com. It works fine in gmail and other clients.

If i have the inline css for the block i want to centre as :

```
<td style="font-family: Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; color: #666666; display:block; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; width:600px;">
```

(note the 600px at the end of the css) the whole `td` will end up left aligned in outlook - see below thumbnail screenshots)

[image]

If i have the inline css for the block i want to centre as (note i dont declare a width with css here) :

```
<td style="font-family: Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; color: #666666; display:block; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;">
```

The text wont have a width in outlook (see below screenshots).

[image]

Any ideas ?

This is the full html and css im using is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html contenteditable="true">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            .dm-user-inserted-image{
                height:auto !important;
                max-width:600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

            td {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

        }
    </style>    
</head>  
<body style="text-align: center; width:600px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding: 0px auto 0px auto;">  
    <center>    
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="responsive-table" align="center" style="text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-left:auto; padding-right:auto;&gt;
            &lt;tbody align=" center"="">   
                <tbody>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td style="font-family: Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; color: #666666; display:block; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis lacus sit amet elit molestie, a dictum elit venenatis. Mauris scelerisque consequat lobortis. Nam quis purus iaculis, suscipit justo ut, aliquam tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>      
    </center>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: heads up: the <center> tag is not supported in HTML5:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope this will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html contenteditable="true"><head>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            .dm-user-inserted-image{
                height:auto !important;
                max-width:600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

            td {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

        }
    </style>

</head>




<body style="text-align: center;">


<center style="max-width:600px; display:inline-block">


    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="responsive-table">


            <tbody>

                <tr align="center">
                    <td style="font-family: Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; color: #666666; display:block; text-align: center; line-height: 30px;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis lacus sit amet elit molestie, a dictum elit venenatis. Mauris scelerisque consequat lobortis. Nam quis purus iaculis, suscipit justo ut, aliquam tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

    </table>


</center>



</body></html>
```

Comment: thanks, it works well in some browser but in Outlook 2013 and others it breaks and becomes full width - see this screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/SxhEz4M.png - any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

just use this code it will align content in center

it will work with

gmail,
yahoo,
outlook,
on mac mail  app,
windows mail app

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" style="Margin:0px; Padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:rgb(255,255,255);max-width:600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <p>hi</p>
                                  </td>
                                  <tbody>
       <tr>
                              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get my email template to center in all version of Outlook. Most noticeably in Outlook 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013.

[image]

I have included the code used in making this centering here at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/kvann/505d65f843fdc590983b)

```
<table width="100%">
    ...
      <table width="600">
        ...
          <table width="600">
            ...
               <table width="100%">

                   Start of your actual email
```

The code above works for me and for whatever reason, wrapping your content around 4 different tables seems to work for all version of Outlook desktop